# Create a custom function Jquery with this code

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a function with this code to pass it by parameter "wifi" (the attr data) and ".wifis" (the class of the div). How can I do it? Thanks

```js
$('.info_hover').click(function() {
  var idRepeat = $(this).attr("data-repeat");
  var data = $(this).attr("data");

  if (data == "wifi") {
    if ($('.wifis[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').hasClass('d-none')) {
      $('.wifis[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').removeClass('d-none');
    } else {
      $('.wifis[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').addClass('d-none');
    }
  }
  if (data == "tv") {
    if ($('.tvs[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').hasClass('d-none')) {
      $('.tvs[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').removeClass('d-none');
    } else {
      $('.tvs[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').addClass('d-none');
    }
  }

  if (data == "movil") {
    if ($('.moviles[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').hasClass('d-none')) {
      $('.moviles[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').removeClass('d-none');
    } else {
      $('.moviles[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').addClass('d-none');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want your function to do. Could you explain what you've tried, and what result you expect?

Comment: @BenHull I have a laravel for loop that outputs multiple DOM elements (like divs) with the same class. What it is showing is a button that when pressed, shows these divs. The data repeat picks up the $ i of the loop. And data picks up the type of div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut down all the duplication by creating a hashmap of the various classes.

Then you can simplify the add/remove classes using toggleClass()

Something like:

```
const selectors = {
    wifi: '.wifis',
    tv: '.tvs',
    movil: '.moviles'
  }

$('.info_hover').click(function() {
  var idRepeat = $(this).attr("data-repeat");
  var data = $(this).attr("data");    

  // TODO: should validate there is a selector
  const $el = $(selectors[data] + '[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']')
  $el.toggleClass('d-none')

});
```

Comment: and how can i check this? `if(data == "wifi")...`

Comment: Check if you have a selector that matches `data` ....  `if(selectors[data])`

Comment: @jagcweb note that you don't need that check with this logic due to its use of `toggleClass()`

Answer (score -2):

It can be done like this

```
$('.info_hover').click( function(){
    var idRepeat = $(this).attr("data-repeat");
    var data = $(this).attr("data");
    _fun(data, idRepeat, _class_selector_value);      
});

function _fun(data,idRepeat, _class_selector_value) {
    if(data == "wifi"){
            if($('.'+_class_selector_value+'[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').hasClass('d-none')){
                $('.'+_class_selector_value+'[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').removeClass('d-none');
            }else{
                $('.'+_class_selector_value+'[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').addClass('d-none');
            }
        }
        if(data == "tv"){
            if($('.tvs[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').hasClass('d-none')){
                $('.tvs[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').removeClass('d-none');
            }else{
                $('.tvs[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').addClass('d-none');
            }
        }

        if(data == "movil"){
            if($('.moviles[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').hasClass('d-none')){
                $('.moviles[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').removeClass('d-none');
            }else{
                $('.moviles[data-repeat=' + idRepeat + ']').addClass('d-none');
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Incase you need to use class variable for data == "tv" or data == "movil", then _class_selector_value varaible can be used as in wifi section

Comment: All you appear to have done here is abstract the existing logic to its own function and added some variables which you don't define and therefore cause errors?

Comment: please check the answer is as per the sample code provided...before marking it down consider the solution is provided as per the same code provided in question